# ffmpeg: Publisher Metadata in VLC

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, vlc

I'm trying to restream an audio stream. From all my metadata, the only one that can be changed is the title.

I would like to remove FFmpeg from "publisher" if possible.

The command that I use:

```
ffmpeg -i https://blabla.com/stream.mp3 -map_metadata -1 -metadata title="STREAM FM" -metadata publisher="STREAM FM" -metadata copyright="STREAM FM" -metadata genre="Something" -metadata encoded_by="Stream" -metadata network="STREAM FM" -ar 44100 -b:a 320k -f flv rtmp://ip:port/live/streamfm
```

Thank you!

Comment: Share full log for the command (do a short run, add `-t 30`). How are you checking the tags in the output?

Comment: Here is the log: https://pastebin.com/zRN5a2kb

Comment: Log shows STREAM_FM as publisher.

Comment: I know, but as example VLC doesn't agree with that: https://i.ibb.co/xmZnQwX/vlc.png

Comment: That's for a HLS playlist, not a FLV stream.

Comment: I use this ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-media-server ) to convert my streams from RTMP to HLS/DASH/FLV. I need HLS for my TV, which won't play MP3s unfortunately. I was thinking that the ffmpeg instance from NMS would change the metadata, but if it is so then why it takes the title metadata? L.E. It seems like the FLV stream has all metadata. NMS doesn't seem to like streaming to it in any other format than FLV tho...

Comment: Change the output from the ffmpeg command to a flv file on disk instead of a RTMP stream. Check the saved file.

Comment: Again, the flv file has all the metadata but I need to change it for the HLS stream. Having the metadata on FLV doesn't help me really.

Comment: If the FLV file has the desired metadata, then there's nothing to be changed in ffmpeg. The issue is downstream.